# ESLint: disallow empty lines inside function body

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I strongly believe that empty lines inside the body of a function are code smells indicating that we need to perform refactoring to break the function apart.

But among the existing rules in ESLint (`no-multiple-empty-lines`/`lines-between-class-members`, etc.), including those presented in popular plugins, I could not find a rule that will **restrict me from the use of empty lines inside the body of a function**. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

This is bad:

```
function add(a, b) {
  const result = a + b;

  return result;
}

const multiply = (a, b) => {
  const result = a * b;

  return result;
}
```

This is good:

```
function add(a, b) {
  const result = a + b;
  return result;
}

const multiply = (a, b) => {
  const result = a * b;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty weird opinion to hold, especially to strongly believe that, so you'll probably need to write your own plugin to take care of that.

Comment: Ok, can you elaborate, please, what exactly is weird here?

Comment: Strongly believing that no white space should exist in functions is odd. White space plays a very important role in readability, so disallowing it is weird. ESLint plugins exist for all common needs, but this is anything but common, hence you'll likely need to write your own.

Comment: Check my comment to doberkofler answer. I briefly described why white spaces is a code smell.

Comment: There is always so many different use cases, but I would definitively not call the use of `white spaces` a `code smell` in JavaScript ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I personally strongly believe that empty lines are of paramount importance to make code more readable.
Anyway: did you check out the `padding-line-between-statements` rule?

If your goal is preventing complex function rather use `max-lines-per-function` and `complexity`.

Comment: Yes I did. I only need to disallow empty lines inside function bodies, no anywhere else.

Comment: I still believe it's a bad idea and I'm pretty sure there is no such rule in eslint. I guess it will be hard to convince the eslint team to add such a rule but you can always create your own custom rule.

Comment: Ok, this is not the main topic of this question, but I will briefly explain. Developers use empty line to separate code blocks. Functions do exactly the same. And if developers continue to add new blocks of code separating them with empty lines we end up having monster function. This is typical mistake of unexperienced developers.

Comment: "Functions do exactly the same." No, a function is giving a specific name to a code block and extracting it out so it can be referenced and reused from multiple locations.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your feedback. If your goal is preventing function from getting too big, you should rather use the rules `max-lines-per-function` and `complexity`.

Comment: Exactly! This is why I always suggest moving empty lines separated blocks to another functions. We will give a name to them and will not be forced to read all statements - just short descriptive summary (name). Remember that if you divided code to blocks with empty lines - they are already logically separated.

Comment: My goal is to disallow empty lines, `complexity` is a different rule.

Comment: I understand the goal in trying to keep functions clean and rather small and promote this using quite restrictive `max-lines-per-function` and `complexity` warnings. Not allowing blank lines seems odd to me but it might be the way to go in your code base. eslint does not support this.